# The natural numbers $a, b, c$, formed by the same $n$ digits $x$, $n$ digits $y$, and $2n$ digits $z$ satisfy $a^2 + b = c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given that the natural numbers $a, b, c$ are formed by the same $n$
>   digits $x$, $n$ digits $y$, and $2n$ digits $z$ respectively. For any
>   $n \geq 2$, find the digits $x, y, z$ such that $a^2 + b = c$

Greetings, I was doing this question above and I couldn't figure out how to do.

Here's my progress so far:

> The relation $a^2 + b = c$ means $$(xxx...x)^2 + (yy..yy) = (zzz...zz)$$ where the $x\text{ and }y$ are $n$ in number and the $z$ is in $2n$ in number. This simplifies to $$x^2(11···1)^2 +y(11···1) = z(11···1)$$
>   and I couldn't figure out further. :(

By some trial and error, I found $(333)^2 + 222 = 111,111$.

Any help would be appreciated. I tried but couldn't find out even a similar question somewhere else. Please inform if this question has been asked before.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^i \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Thus, as you've shown,

$$x^2 f^2(n) + yf(n) = zf(2n) \implies f(n)\left(x^2 f(n) + y\right) = zf(2n) \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Also, note that

$$f(2n) = 10^n f(n) + f(n) = f(n)\left(10^n + 1\right) \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Thus, substituting that into \eqref{eq2} and dividing by the common factor of $f(n)$ gives

$$x^2f(n) + y = z(10^n + 1) \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

First, there's the trivial case of $x = y = z = 0$. The rest of this solution will assume that $z \gt 0$. Next, note that

$$f(n) = \frac{10^n - 1}{9} \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

Thus, substituting \eqref{eq5} into \eqref{eq4} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x^2\left(\frac{10^n - 1}{9}\right) + y & = z(10^n + 1) \\
x^2(10^n - 1) + 9y & = 9z(10^n + 1) \\
x^2(10^n) - x^2 + 9y & = 9z(10^n) + 9z \\
(x^2 - 9z)(10^n) & = x^2 - 9y + 9z
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

The RHS is less than $100$ (update: actually, it's less than $1000$, but it can be $100$; see the end for more details) and greater than $-10$, so for $n \ge 2$, this means that $x^2 - 9z = x^2 - 9y + 9z = 0$. Note $x^2 - 9z = 0$ occurs only for $x = 3, z = 1$ and $x = 6, z = 4$. This gives, from $x^2 - 9y + 9z = 0$, that $y = 2$ for the first part and $y = 8$ for the second part.

Another way to see this is that the RHS of \eqref{eq4}, as $z$ is a digit, in base $10$, would be $z$, followed by $n - 1$ zeros, and then $z$ again. On the LHS, $y$ is just a single digit. This means for $n \ge 2$, the digits in $x^2f(n)$ must basically all "disappear" when $y$ is added, i.e., $x^2f(n)$ must be just slightly less (i.e., $\lt 9$) than a power of $10$. Checking the squares of $x$ multiplied by $11$, you can see this only occurs if $x = 3$, so $x^2 = 9$ (with it being $1$ less than a power of $10$), or $x = 6$ so $x^2 = 36$ (with it being $4$ less than a power of $10$). For $x = 3$, this means $z = 1$, which requires that $y = 2$, while for $x = 6$, this means $z = 4$ and $y = 8$.

Note the second solution comes from the first one by multiplying by $4$ in \eqref{eq4}. You can see this changes $x = 3$ to $x = 6$, $y = 2$ to $y = 8$ and $z = 1$ to $z = 4$.

In conclusion, there are $3$ solutions, with the sets of digits $(x,y,z)$ being $(0,0,0)$, $(3,2,1)$ and $(6,8,4)$.

Update: As I saw from the answer by [fleablood](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/280126/fleablood), I made a mistake in my handling of \eqref{eq6}. The RHS of it is definitely less than $1000$, so what I wrote above is true for $n \ge 3$. However, the RHS can be equal to $100$, which means that for $n = 2$, there's also the solution $(8,3,7)$.

Comment: Great Answer! +1. However, there is one more solution I found that didn't make it in the question. It is $666^2 + 888 = 444,444$

Comment: @Vasu090 Thanks. However, as you pointed out & I realized later, my solution is the only one for larger values of $n$. I'm working on determining & proving it for all the various cases. Please be a bit patient with me while I work on solving this fully. Thanks.

Comment: OK. No problem John. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Vasu090 I realized my mistake and have corrected it. Sorry for not seeing it sooner. As you can see, there's actually $2$ sets of digits $x,y,z$ which work. The second solution includes $66^2 + 88 = 4444$, your value for $n = 3$, $6666^2 + 8888 = 4444 4444$, etc.

Comment: @Vasu090 I determined there's a simpler, more direct way to determine the solutions. I've added this to my answer, but also left the original arguments as well.

Comment: Hey John. I really thank you for the amazing answer. I am just a beginner and I really want to ask: Where did you get the knowledge to solve these kind of problem? In other words, from where did you learn math? I really also want to be a math wiz who can answer these difficult problems. Thanks :)

Comment: @Vasu090 As I found in high school & university, such as from doing extremely well on various math contests, I seem to have a natural knack for solving challenging math problems. Nonetheless, natural ability only took me so far, and I've also worked at it to improve my ability. Like with anything else, a lot of practice and hard work is required to do really well, such as solving these difficult type problems. Just keep working at it yourself is my best advice if you want to be able to answer the more difficult problems yourself.

Comment: @Vasu090 It's quite late for me here (almost 1 a.m.), so it was also late when I answered this, which is not a good excuse, but it's a factor in my mistake to miss one solution. I've updated my answer to explain this, plus fleablood's answer gives more details.

Answer (score 2):

If we let $1_n= \underbrace{1111....1}_{n}$

$a^2 + b = c$

$\frac {a^2}{1_n} + \frac {b}{1_n} = \frac {c}{1_n}$

$x^2*1_n + y = z*(10^n + 1)$

Let's think about what that means:

If $x^2 = 10j + k$ we have

$10j + k + y \equiv z$.  And we carry $j$ or $j+1$

Then we have $j +k (+1)\equiv 0$.  Which means $j+k(+1) = 10$.

This can occur if:

$x=1$ so $k=1$ and $j=0$, $j+k(+1) \equiv 1,2 \not \equiv 0$.

$x = 2$ so $k=4$ and $j=0$, $j+k(+1) \equiv 4,5\not equiv 0$.

$x=3$ so $k=9$ and $j=0$ and $j+k(+1)\equiv 0$ if we carry.

$x=4$ so $k=6$ and $j=1$ and $j+k(+1)\not \equiv 0$.

$x=5$ so $k=5$ and $j=2$ and $j+k(+1)\not \equiv 0$.

$x=6$ so $k=6$ and $j=3$ and $j+k+1\equiv 0$.

$x=7$ so $k=9$ and $j=4$ and $j+k(+1) \not \equiv 0$.

$x=8$ so $k =4$ and $j=6$ and $j+k\equiv 0$.

$x=9$ so $k =1$ and $j = 8$ and $j+k(+1)\equiv 0$.

Now we repeat this and carry again to get the third digit.  Assume $n > 2$  As $j+k(+1) = 10$ we must carry $1$ and get $j+k+1$ so this can only happen if $j+k+1 = 10$; not $j+k=10$.

So this can occur if:

$x=3; k=9;j=0$ and $z= j+1=1$ and $9+y \equiv 1$ so $y = 2$.

$x=6; k=9;j=3$ and $z = j+1 = 4$ and $36+y\equiv 4$ so $y=8$.

$x=9; k=1; j=8$ and $z = j+1=9$ and $81+y\equiv 9$ so $y=8$ but.. then we don't carry the $1$.  we must have $y=18$ but that's not a single digit.

But if $n = 2$ we can have:

$x^2 = 10j + k$ and $x^2*11 = 100j + 10(k+j) + k$ and $x^2*11 + y= 100j + 10(k+j) + k+y$ where $k+y = z$ and $k+j = 10$ and $j+1 = z$

Then we can have $x=8;k=4;j=6;z=7$ and $y = 3$. (i.e  $8^2*11 + 3= 707$ or $(88)^2 + 33 = 7777$

Comment: I see from your answer that I made a mistake in my answer. I've updated my answer to reference yours and explain what I did wrong. Thanks for your providing your answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that

$$\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{2n}=
\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n}\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n}=
\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n}\underbrace{0\ldots 0}_{n}+\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n}=
\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n}\cdot1\underbrace{0\ldots 0}_{n}+\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n}=
\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n}\cdot(9\cdot \underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n}+1)+\underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n}$$

So if we set $t=\underbrace{1\ldots1}_n$ 
we can rewrite the equation

$$x^2\cdot \underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n}^2+y\cdot \underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{n}=z\cdot \underbrace{1\ldots 1}_{2n}$$
as
$$xt^2+yt=z(t(9t+1)+t)$$

This simplifies to
$$t(9z-x^2)+(2z-y)=0 \tag{1}$$

Now we have two cases:

**Case 1: $9z-x^2\ne0$:**

Then we have

$$t=\frac{2z-y}{9z-x^2}$$

Because of $x,y,z \in \{0,\ldots,9\}$ and $9z-x^2\ne0$ we have $|2z-y|\le18$ and $|9z-x^2|\ge1.$ So
$|t|\le18$,  and therefore $t=11$.

If we substitute this in $(1)$ we get

$$11x^2+2y=101z$$

Taking this equation $\pmod {11}$ we get

$$y\equiv 2z \pmod{11} $$

and we can calulate $y$ for every digit $z$. For $z=5$ there is no valid $y$, because $y=10$ is not a digit. From $z$ and $y$ we can calculate $x$. For $z=2$ and $y=4$ there is no valid $x$ because the calculated value is a non integer square root.

```
z y x
0 0 0
1 2 3
2 4 *
3 6 *
4 8 6
5 * *
6 1 *
7 3 8
8 5 *
9 7 *
```

**Case 2: $9z-x^2=0$**

Then we also have

$$2z-y=0$$

The number $9z$ must be a perfect square and therefore $z$ must be a perfect square. So we can calculate

```
z x y
0 0 0
1 3 2
4 6 8
9 9 *
```

Because $9z-x^2=2z-y=0$ the equation holds for arbitrary $t.$

So we can conclude that

$$88^2+33=7777$$

and for every $n\ge2$

$${\underbrace{3\ldots3}_{n}}^2+\underbrace{2\ldots 2}_{n}=\underbrace{1\ldots1}_{2n}$$
$${\underbrace{6\ldots6}_{n}}^2+\underbrace{8\ldots 8}_{n}=\underbrace{4\ldots4}_{2n}$$

These are the only solutions.